# Why can I not create a chat room on Software Engineering?

Tags: discussion, chat

As advised [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340637/14965903) I navigated to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new  and I put my question and the relative site. After pressing <kbd>Next</kbd>, the following screen appeared:

[image]

I have reputation 1, if that matters. Yesterday I asked a question, and I was advised to create a room for this question as it was too broad, so I deleted it. I don't know if this matters.

Comment: The something bad happened message is odd, - it might be nice to have a more obvious error message if that's the case. I'm also not sure if SO rep counts for being able to chat on the 'main' chat server.

Comment: Meta has its own chat server and I'm not sure if meta counts for the main chat either....

Comment: I tried to create a room with stack overflow where I have reputation 41, and I got the same error

Comment: @newbiecoder that's because, as the answer clearly states, you need 100.

Comment: Why are you creating a room instead of choosing a chat room with an appropriate topic and asking for help from the people in there?

Comment: The "advise" you saw on MSO is very bad. I added a comment in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The title of your post says you can't create a chatroom on Software Engineering, which would be correct.

Seeing that you can't create a new chatroom unless you earn 100 reputation.
This is documented in the [/privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page of each site. The link can be found in the top right corner of your achievements.

[image].

To participate in chat you need 20 reputation.

Also when creating a chatroom it is not always obvious that you are creating it on a different Stack Exchange site.
If you opt to create a chatroom it will default to creating it on Stack Overflow (in my case). You can select the community you want it associated with as per screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "First, enter a chat room — they're all public by default. You may enter and read the conversation in any room, but you may not talk until you earn 20 reputation." - I was able to talk in different rooms, but I have problem creating one. Thats why I am confused

Comment: I am sorry, I did so - I selected software engineering; I also I tried to create a room with stack overflow where I have reputation 41, but I got the same error message